# Traveling to Germany with passport not matching residence permit

Tags: germany, residence-permits

I am non-EU citizen that normally requires a visa to enter germany. I also hold two valid regular passports under same details except for passport number and expiry date. I am also a legal resident of germany with my passport number and expiry printed on my residence permit card.

I lost the passport that the residence permit is tied to, but I still have my other passport and residence permit alongside a police report. I also have a flight booked tomorrow with urgent matters to attend to in germany.

If I manage to get to the german border (assuming airlines wouldn't be careful enough to check numbers), from a legal perspective, would I be allowed entry (even if it means being pulled to a side room, being questioned and potentially fined)?

I know that the actual solution is to go to the nearest consulate and get another D visa, but that is a significantly slower process. This question is about the legal and practical aspect of that specific case above, not of the best practices.

Comment: With the police report, there should be no problem.